# Mondrian configure Logging

Tags: logging, log4j, mondrian

I'm developing a web app that shows some dashboard panels with data provided by a OLAP cube. I'm using Mondrian as the analytical platform. Currently, I have everything working. The dashboard works fine with the data provided by Mondrian.

Now, I want to access the query logs from Mondrian, to check their execution time, etc. I've checked the [docs](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/configuration.php) but I couldn't make it work: I can't understand what it means.

Then I've searched for tutorials, but all of them talk about a `log4j.xml` file in the folder `tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/classes`. The thing is that I only have a `log4j.properties` file in that folder.

Can you help me getting logging to work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [how the Pentaho Business Analytics Server does it](http://source.pentaho.org/svnroot/bi-platform-v2/tags/4.5.0-stable/bi-platform-plugin-actions/res/log4j/log4j.xml).

Place the `log4j.xml` file in your `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Good luck!

Will

Comment: Thks for your reply! I created a log4j.xml file with the content of the link u gave me, and i saved it in tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/classes. I restarted mondrian, and tryed to execute some queries but no log files were created..According to the log4j.xml file above, logs will be saved in tomcat/webapps/mondrian/WEB-INF/logs/ but that folder stills empty..What could i be missing?

Comment: Ok this was my bad...I guess i was doing the things right all the time, but it i forgot that i had no permissions to write in the folder where the logs should be saved..It's not the first time i do these mistakes when i'm working with Linux and the permissions on the file system. Thks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error when your log4j.properties are not present in the classpath.
For maven project you should put log4j.properties or log4j.xml in
src/main/resources folder. File in resources will be included in classpath so log4j can read it